# Ошибка в связи с отсутствием hmac_ctx в проекте под OpenSSL 1.0.2e

Tags: c, openssl

Хочу использовать в проекте OpenSSL. Проследовал всем инструкциям: слинковал, настроил подхват хедеров, но получаю единственную ошибку при компиляции:

```
Error   38  error C2079: 'hmac_ctx' uses undefined struct 'hmac_ctx_st'
```

Код: `HMAC_CTX hmac_ctx;`

В хедере:

```
typedef struct hmac_ctx_st HMAC_CTX;
```

По-идее, `hmac_ctx_st` должен быть определен в `hmac.h`, но его там нет.

---

Происхождение ошибки не очень понятно, т.к. в [нескольких](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242665/understanding-engine-initialization-in-openssl) [примерах](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461819/what-is-the-c-equivalent-of-phps-hash-hmac-function/7461837#7461837) все нормально используется. Не знаю, где может быть неправильно - буду признателен за любые подсказки - возможно, я просто неправильно что-то подключил.